# How to move up 1 of 3 columns up. Using Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, multiple-columns

I think i have simple problem. I have 3 columns called **Left**, **Middle**, **Right** obviously ^^

Width of these columns is set to **20%-65%-15% (Left-Mid-Right**). I'd need set the left columns at the same line menu is.

**index.html**

```
    <div class="header-IMG">
      <h1>IMG</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="header-menu">
      <horizontal-menu></horizontal-menu>
    </div>
    <div class="Parent">
      <div class="left">
        <vertical-menu></vertical-menu>
        <center>
          <h1>Left</h1>
        </center>
      </div>
      <div class="middle">
        <center>
          <h1>Middle</h1>
        </center>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <center>
          <h1>Right</h1>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Styles**

```
.Parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 2px solid red;
  color: white;
}

.middle {
  width: 65%;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}

.right {
  width: 15%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

For better imagination i send the image from my localhost here:

[image]

I tried set to **.left** *`position: absolute`* and then set top property but i think there must be something smarter cuz in this case i had to set padding to middle...

Comment: Have you investigate CSS grid and order properties?

Comment: I think.. I went for flexbox cuz usualy its much easier then grid so...

Answer (score 1):

As commented A.Haworth, what about css grid!

Lot of writing saying to use grid for website, not flex. Use flex for 1 element and elements inside it.

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 65% 15%;
  gap: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#div1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 2;
  background-color: rgba(143, 36, 28, 0.5);
}

#div2 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 4;
  background-color: rgba(148, 208, 189, 0.5);
}

#div3 {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
  background-color: rgba(170, 154, 160, 0.5);
}

#div4 {
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4;
  background-color: rgba(11, 38, 185, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="div1">div1</div>
  <div id="div2">div2</div>
  <div id="div3">div3</div>
  <div id="div4">div4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks good! I must learn more about grid. Thank you :)